# PowerShell -like formatting

Tags: regex, powershell, syntax

I am trying to test if a string is in one of two formats:  Title (Year) or Title (Year) [Addl]

For the first, this works: `if ($name -like "* (*)")...`

For the second, this does not work: `if ($name -like "* (*) [*]")...`

I know the brackets make it think it is a regular expression.  How do I make it not a regular expression?

Thanks for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 4):

For [Wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) in PowerShell, the escape character is the **backtick `` ` ``**:

```
'Title (Year)' -like '* (*)'             # => True
'Title (Year) [Addl]' -like '* (*) `[*]' # => True
```

One way to test this is using [`[WildcardPattern]::Escape(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern.escape?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#system-management-automation-wildcardpattern-escape(system-string)):

```
[WildcardPattern]::Escape('[]') # => `[`]
```

If you want to test the pattern using [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2) you would be using the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators), and the escape character would be the **backslash `\`**:

```
'Title (Year)' -match '^\w+\s\(\w+\)$'                # => True
'Title (Year) [Addl]' -match '^\w+\s\(\w+\)\s\[\w+]$' # => True
```

And, as [briantist's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) points out, you can use [`[regex]::Escape(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-6.0) to escape regex special characters:

```
[regex]::Escape('()[]') # => \(\)\[]
```

Comment: Very nice! I love that I'm still learning things about PowerShell; I'm a big fan of `[RegEx]::Escape()` and never realized that there was a `[WildcardPattern]` class with an escape.

Comment: @briantist thank you! Worth adding `[RegEx]::Escape()` to the answer now you mention it. I learnt about `WildcardPattern` from mklement0 :)

Comment: heheh yeah every @mklement0 answer blows my mind

Comment: @briantist same!

Comment: Thank you, very much, for your assistance.

Comment: @BW_Wyo happy to help, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it was helpful